# Download .wav files

Tags: php, html, codeigniter, codeigniter-3, codeigniter-download

I have `.wav` files that I want to download. I am trying to download them but it does not fit, it came out downloading .mp3 but not .wav.

I share my code:

> Button that triggers the controller's method and passed as a parameter
>   the name of the file (in-171-115-20180502-163053.wav).

This is where i am calling download method

```
<a type="button" class="btn btn-primary" href="<?=base_url()?>index.php/login_controller/download_audio/<?php echo($archivowav);?>">
<i class="fa fa-download"></i> Descargar
</a>
```

> Function that performs the download of the file.

```
public function download_audio($audio) {
  $path = file_get_contents(base_url()."assets/grabaciones/".$audio); // get file name
  force_download($audio, $path); // start download`
}
```

> This is the error that marks me.

[image]

Comment: check with other browser and see the what is the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hope this will help you :**

Make sure u have loaded `download` helper in your controller or in `autolaod.php` and set file path using `FCPATH`

```
$autoload['helper'] = array('download');
```

Your `download_audio` method should be like this :

```
public function download_audio($audio) 
{
    if ( empty($audio))
    {
        $file_path  = FCPATH."assets/grabaciones/".$audio;
        force_download($file_path, NULL);
    }
}
```

Or simply do with `anchor` like this :

```
<a href="<?=site_url('assets/grabaciones/'.$archivowav);?>" download>
   <i class="fa fa-download"></i> Descargar
</a>
```

For more : https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/download_helper.html